# Is there a way to get text from a html textbox using js?

Tags: javascript, html

Now, I know this has been posted before. Read it before reporting. I want to try and make a script that gets text from a textbox, and the textbox has code that the user writes. Right now I have a script that can open it in a new window, but

```js
  const el = document.getElementById('externalLink');

  // Create a content for a new page with a script in it
  const newPageContent = `
<DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>some code</title>
</head>
<body contenteditable>
<h1>Some editable text</h1>
</body>
  `;

  // Listen on "click" event
  el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Create a new window on click
    const w = window.open('', '_blank');

    // Write your content to it
    w.document.write(newPageContent);
  });
```

```html
<!-- Your link !-->
<a id="externalLink" href="#/">Click to run the code</a>
<br>
<input type="text" name="Codebox" value="Code here...">
```

But the script "`var Codebox = document.getElementsByName('txtJob')[0].value`" just gets run as a html script, thus makeing it literally say "var Codebox = document.getElementsByName('txtJob')[0].value" on the result page. If there is a way to bypass this, or if i'm just doing it incorrectly, could someone please help me? That would be great! :)

Comment: I don't see that line in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `id` to `input` tag and get the value of it using `document.getElementById('...').value` as follows.

```js
const el = document.getElementById('externalLink');

// Create a content for a new page with a script in it
const newPageContent = `
  <DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <title>some code</title>
  </head>
  <body contenteditable>
    <h1>Some editable text</h1>
  </body>
`;

// Listen on "click" event
el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  const codeValue = document.getElementById("codeBox").value;
  console.log('Code Value', codeValue);

  // Create a new window on click
  const w = window.open('', '_blank');

  // Write your content to it
  w.document.write(newPageContent);
});
```

```html
<!-- Your link !-->
<a id="externalLink" href="#/">Click to run the code</a>
<br>
<input type="text" name="Codebox" id="codeBox" value="Code here...">
```

Comment: <a id="externalLink" href="#/">Click to run the code</a>
<br>
<input type="text" name="Codebox" id="codeBox" value="Code here...">
<script>
const el = document.getElementById('externalLink');

// Create a content for a new page with a script in it
const newPageContent = `
document.getElementById('Codebox').value
`;

// Listen on "click" event
el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

Comment: e.preventDefault();
  
  const codeValue = document.getElementById("codeBox").value;
  console.log('Code Value', codeValue);

  // Create a new window on click
  const w = window.open('', '_blank');

  // Write your content to it
  w.document.write(newPageContent);
});
</script>

Comment: That just makes a page say "document.getElementById('Codebox').value" on it...